# SQL Group by fixed list of values

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, fixed

If I have two columns:

```
col1    col2     amount
1       2         15
2       3         12
1       3         10
3       1         4
3       2         3
```

And I perform a group by col1,col2 then I get a row for each combination (present) in the data.

My problem though is, that I dont always have all combinations, but I would want to return a row of each combination still. So if there isn't a combination. for example 2 -> 1 then I would want its value to be 0.

Can I somehow specify the "levels" of the group by?

I'm using SQL Oracle.

and the outcome I would want is:

```
1 -> 2   15
1 -> 3   10
2 -> 1   0
2 -> 3   12
3 -> 1   4
3 -> 2   3
```

With their respective amount, and 0 if they dont exist, or null works. ( I have a filter to exclude where col1 and col2 are same)

Comment: What DBMS and version are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL etc.

Comment: Thanks, have done both. Oracle sql is what I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate all the rows using `cross join` and then filter for the ones you want:

```
select c1.col1, c2.col2, coalesce(t.amount, 0)
from (select 1 as co1l from dual union all
      select 2 as co1l from dual union all
      select 3 as co1l from dual
     ) c1 cross join
     (select 1 as co12 from dual union all
      select 2 as co12 from dual union all
      select 3 as co12 from dual
     ) c2 left join
     t
     on t.col1 = c1.col1 and t.col2 = c2.col2
where c1.col1 <> c2.col2;
```